# É possível filtrar um p:dataTable quando o atributo filterBy é uma lista de obejtos?

Tags: java, primefaces, java-ee

Estou usando o componente P:dataTable do Primefaces e estou tendo problema no filtro. Tenho uma lista de Email de Setores e dentro dessa lista tenho uma outra lista com os alias de cada email.

Código:

```html
            <h:panelGroup id="tabelaEmails" >
                <div class="tabelaEmails" >
                    <p:dataTable id="tabelaFiltro" var="item" value="#{emailSetorBean.sessionBean.itemPagina.listaEmailSetor}" 
                                 widgetVar="dataWidget" 
                                 emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado com os dados buscados.">

                        <p:column filterBy="#{item.email}" headerText="E-Mail" filterMatchMode="contains"
                                  filterValue="#{emailSetorBean.sessionBean.filtroAlteracao}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.email}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column filterBy="#{item.descricao}" headerText="Descrição" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.descricao}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column filterBy="#{item.setor.descricao}" headerText="Setor" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.setor.descricao}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Alias" filterBy="#{item.listaAlias}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:dataTable var="alias" value="#{item.listaAlias}" >
                                <p:column>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{alias.email}"/>
                                </p:column>
                            </h:dataTable>
                        </p:column>                        
                    </p:dataTable>
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

A última coluna é onde ficam os alias. coloquei filterBy="#{item.listaAlias}" só que a listaAlias é uma lista do tipo Email, que por sua vez tem os atributos idGoogle e E-mail. Eu queria filtrar pelo E-mail. Existe alguma maneira de se fazer isso usando o componente?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi por meio de uma "gambearra".

Na classe Email redefini o método toString. Aí ficou assim:

```html
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.email;
    }
```

E aí no trecho do filterBy chamei o toString da lista. Deu certinho:

```html
                        <p:column headerText="Alias" filterBy="#{item.listaAlias.toString()}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:dataTable var="alias" value="#{item.listaAlias}" >
                                <p:column>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{alias.email}"/>
                                </p:column>
                            </h:dataTable>
                        </p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce por utilizar o DataTable - Lazy

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

```
@Override
    public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
        List<Car> data = new ArrayList<Car>();

        //filter
        for(Car car : datasource) {
            boolean match = true;

            if (filters != null) {
                for (Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    try {
                        String filterProperty = it.next();
                        Object filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);
                        String fieldValue = String.valueOf(car.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(car));

                        if(filterValue == null || fieldValue.startsWith(filterValue.toString())) {
                            match = true;
                    }
                    else {
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        match = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(match) {
                data.add(car);
            }
        }

        //sort
        if(sortField != null) {
            Collections.sort(data, new LazySorter(sortField, sortOrder));
        }

        //rowCount
        int dataSize = data.size();
        this.setRowCount(dataSize);

        //paginate
        if(dataSize > pageSize) {
            try {
                return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                return data.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));
            }
        }
        else {
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Dessa forma tem como você saber qual campo do dataTable que está sendo filtrado e o valor, com isso é só inserir os filtros na SQL que realiza a consulta.